# How to remove duplicated line from a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file containing data.

This file could contains duplicated lines.

The line could be repeated many times in the files

I want to remove the duplicated lines (Of curse I have to keep only one copy of a line if the line is duplicated)

For example if my file is containing:

```
aaa1,bbb1,ccc1
aaa2,bbb2,ccc2
aaa1,bbb1,ccc1
aaa3,bbb3,ccc3
aaa2,bbb2,ccc2
```

After executing the command the file should contain:

```
aaa1,bbb1,ccc1
aaa2,bbb2,ccc2
aaa3,bbb3,ccc3
```

How to do that with linux shell bash?

Comment: Ask your professor, or "man sort".  You could use associative arrays, too, but I'm guessing that's beyond where you are in class.

Comment: Look up sort and uniq

Comment: Unleash the power of `awk` ... `awk -F, '!a[$1]++' file`

Comment: Try: `sort yourfile | uniq`